# Set a delay in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, delay, settimeout

I am trying to add a small delay (2 sec) between the loader icon and the success with the data as html.

What I have tried to use is the setTimeout and put in a delay number. This is not working, so I was hoping you could show me what the correct way is.

**My ajax code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    var delay = 2000;

    var res = {
        loader: $("<div />", { class: "loader" })
    };

    $('#search').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "@Url.Action("Find", "Hotel")",
            datatype: "html",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#group-panel-ajax").append(res.loader);
                setTimeout(delay);
            },

            success: function (data) {
                $("#group-panel-ajax").find(res.loader).remove();
                $('#group-panel-ajax').html($(data).find("#group-panel-ajax"));
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

Right now it runs really fast. Hope someone can help.

Comment: That's not how `setTimeout` works. Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) on it?

Comment: Where have you seen `setTimeout` being used as `setTimeout(delay)`? I would find a better source / tutorial / documentation.

Comment: What are you actually trying to delay? Do you want a delay before sending the request? Or do you want a delay after receiving the response and before displaying the results?

Comment: at least give him some time to check how the `setTimeout()` works before answering the question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`setTimeout` should be used inside `success` `function`.

```js
$(function() {
  var delay = 2000;
  var res = {
    loader: $("<div />", {
      class: "loader"
    })
  };
  $('#search').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "@Url.Action("Find", "Hotel")",
      datatype: "html",
      beforeSend: function() {
        $("#group-panel-ajax").append(res.loader);
      },
      success: function(data) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          delaySuccess(data);
        }, delay);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});

function delaySuccess(data) {
  $("#group-panel-ajax").find(res.loader).remove();
  $('#group-panel-ajax').html($(data).find("#group-panel-ajax"));
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

here is something i found when i wanted to do the same :

```
function doStuff()
{
  //do some things
  setTimeout(continueExecution, 10000) //wait ten seconds before continuing
}

function continueExecution()
{
   //finish doing things after the pause
}
```

hope it will help ya

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout()` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    var delay = 2000;

    var res = {
        loader: $("<div />", { class: "loader" })
    };

    $('#search').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "@Url.Action("Find", "Hotel")",
            datatype: "html",
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#group-panel-ajax").append(res.loader);

            },

            success: function (data) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                     $("#group-panel-ajax").find(res.loader).remove();
                     $('#group-panel-ajax').html($(data).find("#group-panel-ajax"));
                }, delay);

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```