# How to delay search function in php for input field to start searching only after 3 characters are typed?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have an input field that is searching over 12000 skill entries already after the first character is typed in. I want to delay the search after 3 characters are typed or when the user stopped typing.

The class name of the input field is:  fre-search-skill-dropdown

Below the code.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="fre-input-field dropdown">
        <label for="skills" class="fre-field-title"><?php _e('Skills', ET_DOMAIN); ?></label>
        <input id="skills" class="dropdown-toggle fre-skill-field" type="text" placeholder="<?php _e('Search freelancers by skills', ET_DOMAIN); ?>" data-toggle="dropdown" readonly>
        <?php $terms = get_terms('skill', array('hide_empty' => 0)); ?>
        <?php if (!empty($terms)) : ?>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-skill">
            <?php if (count($terms) > 7) : ?>
                <div class="search-skill-dropdown">
                <input class="fre-search-skill-dropdown" type="text">
                </div>
            <?php endif ?>
            <ul class="fre-skill-dropdown" data-name="skill">

            <?php
                foreach ($terms as $key => $value) {
                    echo '<li><a class="fre-skill-item" name="'.$value->slug.'" href="">'.$value->name.'</a></li>';
                }
            ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the JS script for search:

```
        $('.fre-search-skill-dropdown').keyup(function() {
        var _this = this;
        $('.fre-skill-dropdown li').each(function(index, el) {
            if($(this).find('a').text().indexOf($(_this).val()) != -1) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
        if($(_this).val() == '') {
            $('.fre-skill-dropdown li').each(function(index, el) {
                $(this).show();
            });
        }
    });
```

Is there a way to achieve this with modifying the php file?

Comment: Sounds like a JS question, not PHP/wordpress. How do you currently check if they are typing? How do you define `stopped typing`, pause for over 5 seconds?

Comment: Yes pausing for 5 seconds is what I meant. The url to the search field is here: https://mycru.io/profiles/

Comment: You should add the current JS to the question. Something like `$('....').length >= 3` and then probably something with a timeout check.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can't be done with PHP (as I've never tried it or seen anyone try it before) but this sounds more like a JS question like @user3783243 pointed out. You could try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/33395278/8016771?

Comment: Thanks guys, I will search the js for that and upload asap

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce a delay before updating the visibility of the items. If the input value changes before that delay expires, cancel that update, and restart the delay. Only when the delay expires, perform the update.

```
var timer = null; // Reference to the currently pending timeout
$('.fre-search-skill-dropdown').on("input", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    clearTimeout(timer); // Clear the pending timeout (if there was one)
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.fre-skill-dropdown li').each(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).find('a').text().indexOf(val) != -1);
        });
    }, 300); // Adapt delay as desired (milliseconds)
});
```

Some other changes:

- `input` is a more interesting event, as it also triggers when input changes via the mouse (drag text in or out) or context menu, or other device.
- `toggle` is a nice jQuery alternative for `show`/`hide`.